# core 2.1 webapi delete with concurrency

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I have a webapi the can delete ok, but I need to make sure that they item can only be deleted if the correct/current version is provided.

My model is like:

```
public class Item {
    public int Id {get;set;}

    .. other properties ...

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version {get;set;}
}
```

I currently have the following endpoint declaration:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   ...
}
```

Can someone please let me know what is the correct way to have the byte[] version sent in order to check before making the delete?

What do i need to change in the delete end point declaration (above) to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your timestamp in request's body.

```
public class DeleteItemRequest {
    public byte[] Version {get;set;}
} 

[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Delete(int id, [FromBody]DeleteItemRequest request)
{
   ...
}
```